# amazon web services cannot find credentials exception

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

When I run the following program, an exception occurs that cannot find the credentials

```
using (IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USWest2)) 
{                  
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = ps1,
        FilePath = path
    };

    PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.PutObject(request);
    richTextBox1.Text = response.ToString();
}
```

Also I have already configured the app.config like this:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="AWSProfileName" value="ashu"/>
      <add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="C:\service_credential\credentials"/>
      <add key="AWSRegion" value="us-west-2" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate the client using `new`, the best approach to do this is using the `AWSClientFactory` and the `StoredProfileAWSCredentials` to create the clients.

> **SoredProfile approach**, with this you must to have sure about the **profile name** and if it exists. Whatever see this example that show you how figure out: https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx1310VG2O81PSY/Referencing-Credentials-using-Profiles

```
var credentials = new StoredProfileAWSCredentials("ashu");
```

> **EnvirementCredential Approach**, with this you must to put the `AWSAccessKey` and `AWSSecretKey` into the App.config/Web.config, and must to be  sure about that and the region was correct.

#### App.config

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="Access_KEY" />
        <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="Secret_KEY" />      
</appSettings>
```

---

```
var credentials = new EnvironmentAWSCredentials();
```

---

```
using (IAmazonS3 s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USWest2)) 
{                  
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = ps1,
        FilePath = path
    };

    PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.PutObject(request);
    richTextBox1.Text = response.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It is showing a error saying EnvironmentAWSCredential could not be found

Comment: sorry, my bad i see that you'r using the stored credentials , i will update my answer,

Comment: the following error pops up App.config does not contain credentials information. Either add the AWSAccessKey and AWSSecretKey or AWSProfileName.

Comment: @Himanshu  did you try this `new StoredProfileAWSCredentials("ashu")`?

Comment: can i manually declare my access key and secret key in app.config

Comment: @Himanshu Yep, and then you will use the first approach that i show you using the `var credentials = new EnvironmentAWSCredentials();`

Comment: how to do that please tell me how to declare my access key and secret key in app.config file

Comment: thank you so much sir i am almost done but it is showing an Exception on the line:      PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.PutObject(request);    the exception discription is access denied please help me on this

Comment: @Himanshu What the region of the bucket that you are trying to access?

Comment: @Himanshu, right, so maybe is something about the permission on the filepath, and not about Aws Access.

Comment: i had to set the permissions of the bucket to everyone can i do it without setting the permission ... initially the permission was granted only to abcdef

Comment: @Himanshu So dont forget to  mark my answer as correct because i answered the question, now i'm helping you with other question.

Comment: @Himanshu you can grantee permission to **Any Authenticated AWS User** with the roles that you want.